# nth-child is hiding all my elements when targeting one

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Not sure if i am using the selector wrong but my markup looks like this

```
<div class = "col-xs-12 plans__articles">
<div class = "foo">....</div>
<div class = "foo">....</div>
<div class = "foo">....</div>
<div class = "foo">....</div>
</div>
```

I want to select the first foo.

```
.foo:nth-child(1n){ }
```

but it applies styling to all of them ?

Answer (score 2):

Specifying `1n` will select *every* `.foo` element. This is like saying *starting at the beginning of the total set with no element initially selected, select every element found when repeatedly stepping **1** position through the set*.

Instead of specifying `1n`, simply specify `1`. CSS will convert this to `0n+1` which is the equivalent of saying *starting with the 1st element in the total set, select every element found when repeatedly stepping **0** positions through the set* (naturally this means that no other elements are hit apart from the one it started with).

```css
.foo:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "col-xs-12 plans__articles">
  <div class = "foo">....</div>
  <div class = "foo">....</div>
  <div class = "foo">....</div>
  <div class = "foo">....</div>
</div>
```

After that, to select the second one in the list, you can simply use `.foo:nth-child(2)` and so forth.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate exactly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

`:first-child` or `:first-of-type` are close to what you want.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child), "The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the first child element of its parent."

[According to CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/), "The :first-of-type selector in CSS allows you to target the first occurence of an element within its container."

In actuality, you'll probably need to do something [closer to this](https://jsfiddle.net/04p5rjun/2/):

```
var target = $('.foo').first();
target.css('border','3px solid red');
target.click(function() {
    // Do whatever you need to do here
    $(this).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
});
```

Comment: i forgot to mention i basically want to select all of them individually and it can't be done in js.

Comment: What do you mean "all of them individually"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: basically i need to make things happen when a certain one has been clicked but it uses ajax to load content in so it gets a bit messy, $(document).on('click','.foo:nth-child(1n)',function(data){ } and i want that for every div and i cant just add a new class for each one because it's all dynamic

Comment: @Jake If you're adding a click handler, you'll definitely need to do that in JS. CSS can't add click handlers. If you're wanting to style an element, or perhaps add some text before or after an element, then you can do that with CSS.

Comment: hahaha yes i know css can't do that :) i'm using this code $(document).on('click','.foo:nth-child(1n)',function(data){ }

Comment: In a nutshell i want the equivalent of using a 0 index, but for css which i thought was nth term. You know what i'll have a proper read through some css selector docs.

Comment: That'll help. I think you may need to select the first element using JS. The two pseudo-classes I gave will help you if you want to select the first element in general or the first element of a type, but not if you're trying to select the first of a specific class.

Comment: As far as nth-child is concerned, here is a great resource to explain it very simply: http://nthmaster.com/